Class dynamics in Elsschot's Cheese
In Willem Elsschot's Cheese, the protagonist Frans Laarmans is happy in his job as a shipping clerk, but is enticed to take on a more prestigious and potentially more lucrative role as a businessman dealing in imported cheese. He seems motivated more by a desire to fit in with the circle of wealthy tycoons around his patron van Schoonbeke than by any entrepreneurial drive. Van Schoonbeke and his friends are presented as unmitigated snobs. For example, rather than introducing Laarmans as a clerk, van Schoonbeke refers to him simply as someone "from the ship-building yards", allowing his friends to assume Laarmans is an engineer. Van Schoonbeke also tells Laarmans about the cheese importer opportunity and encourages him to take it, partly out of kindness but more out of a sense that a mere clerk is not someone whom he can regard as a social equal.
At the end of the novel, Laarmans goes back to his old job, where he is warmly welcomed. He feels at home and at ease in a way that he had not felt in the cheese business. This works well for him, but raises the question of how Elsschot viewed the class dynamics being portrayed here. On the one hand, the businessmen as a class are shown to be unpleasant people. On the other, the trajectory of the novel suggests that a humble clerk should stay in his own sphere and not aspire to greater wealth or social position. Elsschot himself was a successful businessman running his own advertising agency, so it seems somewhat self-serving that from his own perch as a wealthy man, he would portray a clerk as inept, self-aggrandizing, and unfit to run a commercial enterprise.
This bald summary does not do justice to the texture of Elsschot's novel, and Elsschot himself disliked being a businessman. Laarmans is presented with more affection than any of the businessmen, and Laarmans' wife is portrayed as having both intelligence and common sense. This makes the novel's class dyamics complex and interesting. Is Cheese merely a character sketch, with Laarmans alone meant as unsuited to being anything more than a clerk? Is it a satire against those who have ideas above their station? Is it an expression of Elsschot's own desire to find a niche for himself outside of business? Is it a depiction of the snobbery of the rich? Do these strands of the novel combine into a more nuanced critique of occupational hierarchies, class structures, and the difficulty of social mobility? What have scholars and critics had to say about the depiction of class in Elsschot's novel?

"his own perch as a wealthy man". He earned enough to build a holiday residence on the Belgian coast, but other than that, I wouldn't overestimate his wealth.
